# Time limited Shareware

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shareware

I'm thinking about making a time limited full version of my App, so users can try it for example 7 days.

Is there a recommended Obj-C library?

Comment: Time Machine? can you elaborate?

Comment: Yea.. I have to store the first launch date (to check whether the 7 days are done) somewhere and the user should be able to manipulate this data. If I store the first launch date in the App folder, the user could easily restore the App with Time Machine to get another 7 days for using the App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all do not store your data inside the app. Otherwise it would be simple to delete the App from the filesystem and download it again restarting the countdown. Store it in User preferences or Application Support instead. You could use a plist for this. You could also use a hidden file if you like. Just don't make it too complicated or too invasive. Your app can be cracked no matter what security measures you use in the end. Just be fair enough to the end user that could be a prospective customer.

Here is a very nice link on the topic of implementing a time-limited trial in Cocoa:

http://lipidity.com/apple/shareware-licensing-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

Without possibility to protect your data from manipulation/deletion it is not possible to do.
How do yo check, if it is first start of your application, if all your data is wiped out.

Some alternative is "hardcoded" id token and connection to the rest of world  (at least for first start, to grab any kind signed data key)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a server where store UUID's and first time they launched the App. Then, Each time they open your application, it asks your server if they can use it or not. It's harder than store dates on device but if you do that, users will access your application simply changing the date of the device on Settings.